# What type of wrench do I need to disconnect washing machine

Tags: washing-machine

What should I be looking for to disconnect an old Miele washing machine. Connection in a photo below. Water comes in from right. 
[image: water connection]
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried turning it by hand (with gloves on)? It is screwed onto plastic, so it shouldn't be very tight.

Comment: Thanks. Did try, but without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A large pair of  pliers should work. They have a variety of local names including  Tongue-and-groove pliers—also known as water pump pliers, adjustable pliers, groove-joint pliers, arc-joint pliers, Multi-Grips, tap or pipe spanners, gland pliers and Channellocks ( Channellock are a brand of tools)

Comment: You would be loosening the hose connection which is in the upper right-hand corner of the photo. Not the large nut  that is below the blue valve lever  in the lower portion of the photo.  The lower nut is what holds the valve to the plumbing pipe that comes up into the box from below, you would only undo that nut  to replace the valve and only   if you had turned off the water supply upstream from that box.

Comment: The lower box is part of the washing machine hose. Sorry for a bad photo.